# Python subprocess will not run command

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

For some reason I have a subprocess command line that is not running the subprocess command line underneath it and doing the processing it should be.

```
 import subprocess
 import os

 os.chdir('/home/linux/Trial/')
 a = open('Attempts.txt', 'r')
 b = a.readlines()
 a.close()
 for c in range(0, len(b)-1):
     words = list(b[c].split(" "))
     d = len(words)
     e = words[d-1]
     f = b[c].replace(e, 'Hiccup' + str(c) + '.mp4')
     words[d-1] = 'Hiccup' + str(c) + '.mp4'
     print(f)
     command = 'ffmpeg', '-i', words[2], '-ss', words[4], '-to', words[6], '-c:v copy -a copy', words[11]
     print(command)
     subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', words[2], '-ss', words[4], '-to', words[6], '-c:v copy -a copy', words[11]])
```

When I run the following code I get the following output:

```
 ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:02:34 -c:v copy -a copy Hiccup0.mp4
 ('ffmpeg', '-i', 'test.mp4', '-ss', '00:00:00', '-to', '00:02:34', '-c:v copy -a copy', 'Hiccup0.mp4')
```

I get nothing else. When I check no new file has been created called Hiccup0. I have ffmpeg-python installed and updated(made sure of that this morning).

What gives. I see this should work but it doesn't.

Edit:

I decided to try running the subprocess statement in interpretter instead of through the program only. When I run:

```
 subprocess.run('ffmpeg', '-i', 'SR0.mp4', '-ss', '0', '-to', '82', '-c:v', 'copy' ,'-a', 'copy', 'help.mp4')
```

I get the error, bufsize must be an integer. I still ask the same question, what gives? I tried changing everything over to seconds from minutes and hours to make it a digit, as can be seen from the above line, but it still won't work correctly. At least I'm getting an error now, much than just not having it run at all.

I also just tried to put an f into front of 'ffmpeg; and it still gave the same error.

Comment: `'-c:v copy -a copy'` should be `'-c:v', 'copy', '-a', 'copy'`

Comment: I tried changing this and it doesn't make a bit of difference.

Comment: It certainly makes _some_ difference, unless you can put `"-c:v copy -a copy"` in quotes on the shell command line when running ffmpeg by hand and have it not matter there.

Comment: As for the new edit -- you need to pass a single list. **The square brackets are not optional.** That is, in `subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'SR0.mp4', '-ss', '0', '-to', '82', '-c:v', 'copy' ,'-a', 'copy', 'help.mp4'])`, the `[` and `]` are mandatory. When you leave them out, strings are treated as values for other parts of subprocess's argument list, hence one of those strings trying to be treated as `bufsize` (where it's of course not valid).

Comment: Okay, so I just tried       subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'SR0.mp4', '-ss', '00:00:00', '-to', '00:01:22', '-c:v', 'copy' ,'-a', 'copy', 'help.mp4']) and it still does nothing. I'm not getting any errors but when I look no file has been created either. Guess this shortcut to finding the answer isn't going to help,

Comment: It does say returncode=1

Comment: How do you know if you're not getting errors? Your code above doesn't collect stderr. Any well-behaved program (that isn't something like `test` where its specification calls for silently returning falsey values) will write an explanation to stderr when it's exiting with a non-zero returncode.

Comment: My most recent attempts     subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'SR0.mp4', '-ss', '00:00:00', '-to', '00:01:22', '-c:v', 'copy' ,'-a', 'copy', 'help.mp4'],shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
CompletedProcess(args=['ffmpeg', '-i', 'SR0.mp4', '-ss', '00:00:00', '-to', '00:01:22', '-c:v', 'copy', '-a', 'copy', 'help.mp4'], returncode=1)
This is the most I've been able to get out of anything thus far. I'm not an all the time programmer. I maybe write up a program for myself, once every couple of years. I used to have a program able to do what I"m trying to do but sadly lost it in a HD failure.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` -- it throws away all your arguments except the first. (Strictly -- those other arguments populate `$0`, `$1`, and so forth; but because the shell command `'ffmpeg'` never _looks at_ `$0`, `$1` etc, they have no effect).

Comment: Beyond that -- you're setting `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, but then you aren't directing stdout to anywhere it gets saved. You should see ffmpeg writing a usage error complaining that it wasn't given any arguments, when you do finally get that content directed to somewhere you can see it.

Comment: BTW, notice how you're making changes that nobody told you to do? Nobody told you to take out the square brackets. Nobody told you to add `shell=True`. Please try to follow our advice _without_ adding extra/confusing factors in at the same time.

Comment: No problem, by finally experimenting enough and looking around enough I finally managed to answer my own question. It's not stderr, its capture_output=True. That finally got the first part taken care. Now for the second part, that's another story, directly ffmpeg related, not subprocess related. OOPS! Big error on my part. Guess I need to go back and reread what I have in the saved file first on the ffmpeg statements. DRATS!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test with `ffmpeg` but I'm pretty sure `subprocess.run()` will stumble on the double parameters `'-c:v copy -a copy'`. These are escaped so they become *one* argument to the called process.

Compare the following minimal example with almost identical calls to the `echo` command:

```py
subprocess.run(['echo', '-n', '"hello world"'])
# output: "hello world"<no newline>
subprocess.run(['echo', '-n "hello world"'])
# output: -n "hello world"<newline>
```

Comment: I don't see any new line, in either case inserted. Thanks to this though I did try putting the subprocess right into the interpretter instead of trying to run it through a program only. Now I'm getting an error, finally, which I will very shortly add to the original question.

Comment: Without newline, the next prompt will be right behind "hello world" and not on the next line. Anyway, you should see the `-n` popping up in the second case's output which is usually not what you want.

Comment: @Friedrich, ...mind, `-n` isn't POSIX-standardized behavior (the POSIX spec for `echo` explicitly declares output [undefined in its presence](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)), so an `echo` implementation is free to write it to stdout unconditionally, and some do (even bash does, when the `xpg_echo` flag was enabled, which can be done either at compile time or runtime). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113

Comment: @CharlesDuffy seems I picked a poor example. Thanks for pointing this out. Serves me right for trying to write a [mre] on OP's behalf :-)